# Unexpected behavior of UNION ALL operator

Tags: php, mysql, union, union-all

I have the following MySql tables.

Table `tblUsg` defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblUsg` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`ip` VARCHAR(46) NOT NULL,
`dtm` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`huid` BINARY(32) NOT NULL,
`licnm` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`lichld` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`flgs` INT NOT NULL,
`agnt` VARCHAR(256),

INDEX `ix_huid` (`huid`),
INDEX `ix_licnm` (`licnm`),
UNIQUE KEY `ix_lichuid` (`huid`, `licnm`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=0 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And table `tblLics` defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `wosLics` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`licnm` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`desc` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
`maxcpy` INT NOT NULL,
`dtmFrom` DATETIME,
`dtmTo` DATETIME,
`stat` INT NOT NULL,

UNIQUE KEY `ix_licnm` (`licnm`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=0 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I then call the following PHP script when, say, both tables are empty:

```
$link = @mysql_connect($HOSTNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWD);
@mysql_select_db($DBNAME);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);

$res = @mysql_query(
    "SELECT `maxcpy`, `stat`, `dtmFrom`, `dtmTo` FROM `tblLics` WHERE `licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu'\n".
    "UNION ALL\n".
    "SELECT COUNT(*), NULL, NULL, NULL FROM `tblUsg` WHERE `licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu'\n".
    "UNION ALL\n".
    "SELECT COUNT(*), NULL, NULL, NULL FROM `tblUsg` WHERE (`licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu' AND `huid`='a871c47a7f48a12b38a994e48a9659fab5d6376f3dbce37559bcb617efe8662d')"
    , $link);
if($res)
{
    $row0 = @mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $row1 = @mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $row2 = @mysql_fetch_row($res);

    echo("<br/>0::<br/>");
    var_dump($row0);
    echo("<br/>1::<br/>");
    var_dump($row1);
    echo("<br/>2::<br/>");
    var_dump($row2);
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
0::
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL } 
1::
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL } 
2::
bool(false)
```

My question is why my `$row2` is `false` when `$row1` is the array as I would've expected?

Comment: Is it? Do you have a record, which satisfies the where condition in the first query? What is your expected output for an empty result and two recordset with 1 record in each?

Comment: @Pred: No, the tables are initially empty. In that case I would expect my `$row0` to be `false`. Is that not the case?

Comment: Why? Empty + Something = Something. SQL will not reindex the result just because you have an empty set somewhere. How SQL should know if the first query should return 1 or 2 or none or 10k records? To where should it reindex the records (and fill everything before the first record)?

Comment: *"In that case I would expect my `$row0` to be `false`"* -- SQL works with sets, which are **unordered** lists. `mysql_fetch_row()` returns `FALSE` when there is no row to return (either because the query didn't return any or because all the rows were already fetched). Your query returns exactly 2 rows.

Comment: **`mysql` PHP extension is dead** - Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: @axiac: No, mysql php extension isn't dead. Php itself is dead. I'm working on old code, otherwise I would never use php ever again for anything new. It feels like a patch-job for something that should've died 10 years ago.

Comment: @c00000fd It is a fortune, that your question has nothing to do with PHP, but it reveals how you misunderstood the underlaying data store.

Comment: @Pred: What do you mean?

Comment: It means, that it does not matter in which language you want to fetch the result of your query it will be the same (maybe the end of result set is reported another way). Therefore you don't understand how SQL works, and this is why you've expected an 'empty' row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why my `$row2` is false when `$row1` is the array as I would've expected?

You expect to get back 3 rows from your query but it only returns 2 rows.

Your query `UNION`s three `SELECT`s. Each of the last two `SELECT`s always return exactly one row. The first `SELECT` can return 0 rows or more. Because the table is empty it returns exactly zero rows.

`0+1+1`. The query returns exactly `2` rows.

---

**Update:**

You expect the rows to be returned in a specific order but the query doesn't require any sorting. SQL works with sets of rows and the sets, as mathematical objects, are **unsorted** collections (and this is how the SQL handles them).

Without the presence of `ORDER BY` in the query, the rows returned by [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) are not guaranteed to be returned in any order. Not even the order they come from the `SELECT`s is not preserved.

If you want to get the rows in the order you wrote the `SELECT` queries then you have to add an additional column that tells the order and use in in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT `maxcpy`, `stat`, `dtmFrom`, `dtmTo`, 1 AS tableNb
FROM `tblLics`
WHERE `licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*), NULL, NULL, NULL, 2 AS tableNb
FROM `tblUsg`
WHERE `licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*), NULL, NULL, NULL, 3 AS tableNb
FROM `tblUsg`
WHERE `licnm`='zbcdefghijklmnopqrsu'
  AND `huid`='a871c47a7f48a12b38a994e48a9659fab5d6376f3dbce37559bcb617efe8662d'

ORDER BY tableNb
```

This way you know what part of the query generated each of the returned rows.

***Remark***

You don't need the row returned by the second query. It basically tells you how many rows are returned by the first query but you can also know that by counting the rows having `tableNb == 1` in the result set. Since you want the count **after** the actual rows, it doesn't need an additional traversal of the result set, it can be done while listing the rows from the first query.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I misunderstood the meaning of `ALL` in `UNION ALL`. My assumption was that it would include NULLs as well. By bad. So my construction above is pretty much useless. So I'll have to split it up onto 3 separate `mysql_query` calls. Screw concurrency.

Comment: The `ALL` part of `UNION ALL` doesn't remove the duplicate rows. But the first `SELECT` doesn't return any row. Had it return a row full of `NULL`s, that row would have been returned into the final result set.